# Wordpress will not send two different emails to two different email addresses

Tags: php, wordpress, email, switch-statement

I am working on a web app and I am having difficulty getting Wordpress to send two different emails to two different email addresses. I am calling wp_mail twice. The first $message always sends, but the second $confirmation will not send. It doesn't matter if I use a variable to define the "to" or hard code in an email, the $confirmation never sends. I've tried concatenating single quotes to the email just to ensure proper formatting, but nothing.

Does anyone have any knowledge as to how you properly send two different emails using wp_mail?

I will post the snippet of the code I am using for the message. I am using a switch to take customers through an ordering process.

I am fairly new to this, so it's possible I'm missing something with the syntax, but any help would be so so appreciated.

```
    case 5: // Confirmation
    /*if (!isset($order->dumpster_purpose)) {
        wp_redirect('/order');
        exit;
    }*/

    $message = '' . "
ORDER TYPE
------------------------------------------------------------
" . ($order->type == ORDER_TYPE_TEMP ? 'Temporary Rental' : 'Permanent Scheduled Pickup') . "


DUMPSTER INFORMATION
------------------------------------------------------------
Dumpster: {$order->dumpster}
Dumpster Amount: {$order->dumpster_amount}
Purpose for Dumpster: {$order->dumpster_purpose}
Needed for: {$order->dumpster_use}
Schedule Type: {$order->schedule_type}
Disposing of:
";
    foreach($order->disposing_materials as $material) {
        $message.= " - {$material}\r\n";
    }

    $message.= "

DELIVERY INFORMATION
------------------------------------------------------------
Name: {$order->full_name}
";
    if (!empty($order->business_name)) $message.= "Business Name: {$order->business_name}\r\n";
    $message.= "Phone: {$order->phone}
Email: {$order->email}
";
    $message.= "
Address:
{$order->d_address}
{$order->d_city}, {$order->d_state} {$order->d_zip}
";
    $message.= "
Delivery Date: {$order->d_date}
";
    if (!empty($order->instructions)) $message.= "\r\nDelivery Instructions:\r\n{$order->instructions}\r\n";
    if (FALSE && $order->type == ORDER_TYPE_TEMP) {
        $message.= "

BILLING INFORMATION
------------------------------------------------------------
Address:
{$order->b_address}
{$order->b_city}, {$order->b_state} {$order->b_zip}

Card Info:
{$order->card_type}
{$order->card_number}
{$order->card_code}
{$order->card_exp_month}/{$order->card_exp_year}
";
    }

    wp_mail(ORDER_RECIPIENTS, $order->type == ORDER_TYPE_TEMP ? 'Online Dumpster Order' : 'Online Dumpster Quote Request', $message);

        $confirmation = '' . "
ORDER TYPE
------------------------------------------------------------
" . ($order->type == ORDER_TYPE_TEMP ? 'Temporary Rental' : 'Permanent Scheduled Pickup') . "


DUMPSTER INFORMATION
------------------------------------------------------------
Dumpster: {$order->dumpster}
Dumpster Amount: {$order->dumpster_amount}
Purpose for Dumpster: {$order->dumpster_purpose}
Needed for: {$order->dumpster_use}
Schedule Type: {$order->schedule_type}
Disposing of:
";
$email = $order->email;
    wp_mail($email, $order->type == ORDER_TYPE_TEMP ? 'Online Dumpster Order' : 'Online Dumpster Quote Request', $confirmation);
    //session_destroy();
    break;
}
```

Comment: did you check the return value of the `wp_mail` calls? if that comes out true, then it's not a php problem. php's job is the equivalent of running an envelope down to the street corner and tossing it into the mail box. after that, php's done and returns "true"/success. If that mailbox gets nailed by a drunk driver, the mail truck gets lost, the mail plane explodes, blah blah blah, that's not php's problem, and you need to go check the downstream logs (e.g. your mail server)

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure how to even do that. How would you echo the value of the wp_mail calls?

Comment: `var_dump(wp_mail(....))` is the quickest/easiest.

Comment: Ah, yes. Didn't know that could be used on that function. This was the result.

email@email.combool(true)

I replaced my actual email with the fake email when I pasted it.

Comment: so you got a true, which means php successfully handed the email over to the mail server. so you need to go look at the mail server's logs.

Comment: Right on, well that at least gives me a direction to look in. We are on a development site so I wonder if there are settings or a configuration that is blocking multiple calls/emails. Thank you for your help @MarcB.

Comment: well, if there is, it won't be a php thing.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm having the same issue! Both are returning true but I'm just never receiving the second email.